# Postgres query in php with a date variable

Tags: postgresql, php

Can you please help me on below query?

php code://

```
$countdate='2017-01-03';
$countsql='SELECT rucid,"databaseType","countLoggedOn","prodCount","nprodCount","countType" FROM "ru_countLog" WHERE "countLoggedOn"=$countdate';
```

--> It's giving syntax error

> syntax error at or near "$" LINE 1: ...untType" FROM "ru_countLog"
>   WHERE "countLoggedOn"=$countdate

Comment: syntax error at or near "$"
LINE 1: ...untType" FROM "ru_countLog" WHERE "countLoggedOn"=$countdate

Answer (score 1):

Remove the internal double quotes from your query:

```
$countsql = "SELECT rucid, databaseType, countLoggedOn,
             prodCount, nprodCount, countType
             FROM ru_countLog
             WHERE countLoggedOn = $countdate";
```

Note that this query is vulnerable to SQL injection. Consider parametrizing `$countdate`. With http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query-params.php, this would become

```
$countsql = 'SELECT rucid, databaseType, countLoggedOn,
         prodCount, nprodCount, countType
         FROM ru_countLog
         WHERE countLoggedOn = $1';

$result = pg_query_params($dbconn, $countsql, array($countdate));
```

where `$dbconn` is your database connection

Comment: `$countdate` will not be interpreted in your first code sample, as it's within a single-quoted string.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try like this

```
$countdate='2017-01-03';
$countsql='SELECT rucid,"databaseType","countLoggedOn","prodCount","nprodCount","countType" FROM "ru_countLog" WHERE "countLoggedOn"='.$countdate;
```

Hope this help